# Installed python 3.8.3 in redhat 6.7, the following issue occurred with pip3: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available

Tags: python, pip, redhat

When I installed python 3.8.3 on redhat 6.7, I had the following issue when using pip3 install

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting bcrypt==3.2.0
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/bcrypt/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/bcrypt/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/bcrypt/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/bcrypt/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/bcrypt/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/bcrypt/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/bcrypt/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bcrypt==3.2.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for bcrypt==3.2.0
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuDy4.png)

The Python installation steps are as follows

```
yum -y groupinstall "Development tools"
yum -y install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel libffi-devel gcc make


./configure --prefix=/root/soft/python3/python383

make && make install


vim /etc/profile  
PATH=/root/soft/python3/python38/bin:$PATH
export PATH


pip3 config set global.index-url https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/
```

My Linux system is

```
[root@rhel67 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
[root@rhel67 ~]# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-027.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Jul 1 18:23:37 EDT 2015
```

OpenSSL is already installed

```
[root@rhel67 ~]# yum list installed | grep openssl
openssl.x86_64                       1.0.1e-42.el6                      @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201507020259.x86_64/6.7
openssl-devel.x86_64                 1.0.1e-42.el6                      @os_repo
```

When I installed python 3.8.3 on redhat 6.7

Comment: The `./configure` may include output that identifies the problem. I suspect your openssl installation is too old; RH 6.7 dates back to 2015.